# Closing a Web Page

Tags: java, web

Here is part of my code:

```
if(s.equals("Fluff")){
             Desktop c=Desktop.getDesktop();
             c.browse(new URI("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_9kdZ07BCFQ"));
         }
```

I'd like for the user to be able to type 'stop' to kill the web page.  I have looked online, but all I am seeing is window.close().  I tried it, but it didn't work - I think because I am using Desktop instead of window.  How would I go about doing this?

I'm new to coding, so the solution may be obvious, I just don't see it.  Explain thoroughly - I'd like to *learn*, not copy/paste.

Comment: I do not think there in any way to that in java (that I know of). Their is JNI(JNativeInterface) which is a way for java code to use c++ code in a nutshell; it might have a way to shutdown the Web browser or Web page. Another way may be finding the tab that is open and then closing that tab using the execute command from the desktop class.